# How to insert <!--nextpage--> inside php if?

Tags: html

I would like to have a page break after the entry 90. I tried this. But it is not working. What is the error in this code?

```
<?php if ($entry[0] == 90):
echo <!--nextpage-->;
?>
```

Comment: As far as I know, there's not a reliable way to enforce a pagebreak when the CSS media is for screen. You can use a series of client height divs if you absolutely must (such as used in fullscreen js). If this is for print, you can use the css `page-break-after` property.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you don't end your if. Second, the echo  still have to be within quotes, even though you're outputting a comment. So the correct structure would be this:

```
<?php if ($entry[0] == 90):
echo '<!--nextpage-->';
endif;
?>
```